# Using OAuth Token to Access Salesforce via Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: salesforce, pentaho

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration to access Salesforce Data.  What I'd like to do, though, is login to salesforce using OAuth and use the access token to access my data.

Is this something which is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading the kettle source code, the answer here appears to be no.